# Incrementally get all data from source table (in db1) to destination table (in db2) in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have two PostgreSQL databases **db1 = source database** and **db2 = destination database** in a AWS server endpoint. For **db1**, I just have **read rights** and for the **db2** I have both **read and write rights**. **db1 being production database** has a table called 'public.purchases', my task is to get incrementally all the data from 'public.purchases' table in **db1** to a '*to be newly created table*' in **db2** (let me call the table as 'public.purchases_copy'). And every time I run the script to perform this action the destination table which is 'public.purchases_copy' in **db2** needs to be updated without fully reloading the table.

My question is what would be the best way to achieve this task more efficiently. I did quite a bit of research online and I found out that it can be achieved by connecting Python to PostgreSQL using 'psycopg2' module. Me being not so proficient in Python it would be of great help if somebody help me out in pointing out the links in StackOverflow where the similar question was being answered or guide me in what can be done or how this can be achieved or any particular tutorial which I can refer? Thanks in advance.

**PostgreSQL version: 9.5**,
**PostgreSQL GUI using: pgadmin 3**,
**Python version installed: 3.5**

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to do this using python, I would recommend first looking into Postgres own module postgres_fdw, if it is possible for you to use it :

> The postgres_fdw module provides the foreign-data
>   wrapper postgres_fdw, which can be used to access data stored in
>   external PostgreSQL servers.

Details available on [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/postgres-fdw.html), but specifically after you  set it up, you can :

> Create a foreign table, using CREATE FOREIGN TABLE or IMPORT FOREIGN
>   SCHEMA, for each remote table you want to access. The columns of the
>   foreign table must match the referenced remote table. You can,
>   however, use table and/or column names different from the remote
>   table's, if you specify the correct remote names as options of the
>   foreign table object.
>
> Now you need only SELECT from a foreign table to access the data
>   stored in its underlying remote table

For simpler setup, it should probably be best to use readonly db as the foreign one.